# WYSIWYG Trac editor with reStructuredText

Tags: trac, wysiwyg, rst

We're using [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), and using it's inbuilt [reStructured Text](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiRestructuredText) throughout our wiki, since we process our trac wiki pages with another programme and convert them to another format. RST is a more widely available format.

We'd like to have a WYSIWYG editor for editing trac wiki pages. There is [TracWysisygPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWysiwygPlugin), but that only works with trac's wiki syntax. Is there a wysiwyg trac editor plugin that outputs rst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of one.  You might try the mailing list or IRC to see if anyone there knows of one, or is interested in working with you to create one.